# Different ways to ask somebody to wait

Tags: difference, politeness, formality, conversation, interpretation

Are there differences in meaning (and possibly context) of the following three ways to ask somebody to wait? Or is one of these options even ungrammatical?

## 1 *I'm going to ...*

> I'**m just going to make** a quick phone call.
>   Can you wait for me?

## 2 *I'm doing*

> I'**m just making** a quick phone call.
>   Can you wait for me?

## 3 *I'll do*

> I'**ll just make** a quick phone call.
>   Can you wait for me?

Comment: I would say "I have to make a quick phone call." This politely indicates the necessity, since you are inconveniencing the other party.

Answer (score 3):

They all mean exactly the pretty much the same thing, although technically #1 and #3 could imply that the phone call hasn't started yet (but is about to), and #2, **making* implies that you have already started the call (perhaps just started dialing).

The are all grammatically correct, and sound fine, although if it was me, I would probably would say:

> Would you mind waiting for me while I make a quick phone call?

Pretty much the same too.